# Triangle recursion

Tags: java, recursion

So i have a program in which (with recursion) i am supposed to take a user input (int) and draw a backward and then forward triangle according to the number... ex below

User input: 4
(ignore the extra spaces inbetween each,, there should be no extra line inbetween) Result:

```
XXXX 
XXX
XX
X
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
```

I have created a method in which i think should do it but I am having a problem wiht it

This si the code I have so far

n is the input number
z is a counter to try and go between making a backwards/ forwards triangle

```
    public static String drawLine(int n, int z){

            if(n!=0&& z<(n+1)){
                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    System.out.print("X");
                System.out.println();
                z+=1;
                drawLine(n-1,z);

                return"";
            } 
            else{
            if( z==(2*n+1) ) return "";
            z+=1;
            String p = drawLine(n - 1,z);
            p = p + "X";
            System.out.println(p);


           return p;    }

            }
```

the error message is that there is some infinit loop or an over flow, but I cannot find the error....please help!!

Comment: do you want your program to return that string or print that string? If you choose, and stick to one it would be much easier.

Comment: What a lousy example for teaching recursion.... sigh.

Comment: @JimGarrison Actually, there is an elegant recursive way to do this. However, nobody has posted it.

Comment: @Taymon maybe so, but recursion is also an "elegant" solution for Fibonacci and totally wrong from a software _engineering_ perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's a simpler alternative:

```
public static void drawLine(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printChar('X', n);
        drawLine(n - 1);
        printChar('X', n);
    }
}

public static void printChar(char c, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        System.out.print(c);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Notice that you only need *one* parameter for the recursive method; let the recursion take care of printing the right number of chars when it returns *after* reaching the base case (`n <= 0`).

As has been mentioned in the comments, it's better to either return a `String` or print a `String` inside the method, but don't mix both approaches (I chose the latter). Also, it's a good practice to define helper methods for code that gets reused, like `printChar` in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problematic statement:

```
n != 0
```

What if `n = -1`? Your loop will continue endlessly. Try using `n > 0`.